# Extending the Lightning Contextual Help Menu with ISV Documentation

Tags: lightning-experience

Our package in Salesforce has extensive user documentation.

As we prepare for the transition to Lightning we are searching to find ways to keep the documentation near the functionality it documents. This is vital for keeping support costs down.

Most of our clients are going to look for help first in the Lightning contextual help menu: [image: Lightning Contextual Help Menu]

As is, clients will look in this section and only find generic Salesforce help which is an undesirable situation for us.

The problem is this menu does not seem to be customizable, which seems like a huge functionality gap on Salesforce's part. We are looking for information on how or when this will be remedied. Does anyone have any information on the status of this?

Comment: The Idea is here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TpzoQAC